# How to figure out where is the raw data in a table?

Tags: web-scraping, websocket

https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:A

After I access the above URL, I open Developer Tools in Firefox. Then change the date in `HISTORIC PRICES`, then click 'GO'. The table is updated. But I don't see relevant HTTP requests sent in devtools.

So this means that the data has already been downloaded in the first request. But I can not figure out how to extract the raw data of the table. Could anybody take a look at how to extract the raw data from the table? (Note that I don't want to use methods like selenium, I want to stay with raw HTTP requests to  get the raw data.)

EDIT: websocket is mentioned in the comment. But I can't see it in Developer Tools. I add websocket tag anyway in case somebody knows more about websocket can chime in.

Comment: there is a websocket on wss://stream2-300.dataservices.theice.com/ that seems to be used to update the data

Comment: @BertrandMartel I don't see such a thing in Developer Tools of Firefox. How did you figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot extract javascript rendered content without selenium. You can always make use of a headless browser(you don't see any instance on your screen, the only pitfall is that you have to wait until the page fully loads) and it won't bother you anymore.

In other words, all the other scraping libs are based on urls and forms. Scrapy can post forms but not run javascripts.

Selenium will save the day, all you lose is a couple of seconds for each attempt(will be milliseconds if it is run in frontend). You can share page source with driver.page_source and it can be directly used for parsing(as a html text) with BeautifulSoup or whatever.

Comment: That is not the solution that I am looking for. Waiting for the page to fully load is troublesome. It is not clear how long to wait. If waiting too long, then it is a waste of time. I am looking for solutions that is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with requests-html, for example let's grab the first row of the table:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:A'

r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(sleep=7)

first_row = r.html.find('.flex_tr', first=True)

print(first_row.text)
```

Output:

```sh
06/18/2021
146.31
146.83
144.94
145.01
3,220,680
```

As @Nikita said you will have to wait the page loading (here 7sec but maybe less), but if you want to do multiple requests you can do it asynchronously !

Comment: I am not familiar with HTMLSession. But looking at its homepage, it evaluates javascript. How is it different from a headless browser like puppeteer? I don't want to wait as I have many similar pages to download, I can't tell whether the wait is enough for many downloads, hence I can't completely trust the results. But if I set a long wait, it will waste time for those that downloads quickly.

Comment: requests-html uses puppeteer.